# Too many connections error when using Django Channels

Tags: heroku, django-channels, heroku-postgres

I'm probably duplicating at least part of the question, but since everything I found dated years ago and did not work for me, I thought I'd ask.

I have a Django application that uses Django Channels and a Heroku Postgres database (with max of 20 connections). I'm using Django as a server for a quiz game, so there's a lot of reading and writing on the socket part of it. While developing, I started getting 'Too many connections' errors pretty frequently, so I started lowering the `conn_max_age` (600 at the beginning), eventually setting it to 0. The issue remained.

I found another question, where the suggested solution involved gunicorn settings update but I don't use the package at all.

Some other StackOverflow questions lead me to try to solve the issue with connection pools. I tried with `django-db-pool`, as well as `django-postgrespool` and it's fork `django-postgrespool2`. None of them seemed to work for me.

I found that Heroku have experimental Postgres Connection Pooling but I don't know if it'll actually help and since it can't be added through the dashboard, I am reluctant to add it.

Comment: How many dynos are running django channels? The thing is, each time `database_sync_to_async` is used, it seems to create a new connection to the DB which it eventually cleans up but not always. If you're using `asgiref.sync.sync_to_async` in places that access the DB, then it's even worse because it doesn't close the connections. Check for these sensitive parts, then you may be able to reduce the number of DB connections

Comment: Also, check out this section on how to close connections if you're using a custom auth middleware https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html#custom-authentication

Comment: I haven't set a number for the dynos, so according to information on the internet, they must be 2. Sadly, yes, I am using `asgiref.sync.sync_to_async`. I wasn't using any middleware, but I added a custom one. Now connecting to the socket creates 1-3 new connections, and it was creating around 5 before. I guess I'll try to close old connections in other places as well. What I noticed while adding questions from the admin panel is that I again started getting 'Too many connections' error. So I guess the real issue is not with Channels but with Django itself?